# WCF HTTP Post: How to bind Json data to C# Model

Tags: c#, wcf, http-post, data-annotations, poco

I am creating an HTTP Post method to an existing WCF application. The method take a C# object as argument:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UpdateDetails", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public void UpdateDetails(MyObject myObject)
{
   // Some logic
}

public class MyObject
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

If the JSON data has properties called 'Title' and 'Details', they will be mapped to the argument. But I'd like to handle scenarios when those JSON properties are changed. For example, if the sender decide to change 'Title' to 'Event_Title', is there a way to map 'Event_Title' to 'Title' field of MyObject class? Is it can be done by any data annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember(Name = "name_as_it_will_appear_in_json")]`

```
[DataContract]
public class MyObject
{
   [DataMember(Name = "Event_Title")]
   public string Title { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   public string Details { get; set; }
}
```